# jQuery Mobile: Navigation does not open after page change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

In my jQuery Mobile project I have an element `#sidebar` with a toggle icon.

In my base file, just under the #sidebar div I use the following code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="toggle-sidebar">Toggle sidebar</a>
<div id="sidebar"> ... </div>

$('#toggle-sidebar').on('click', function() {
   $('#sidebar').toggleClass('visible');
});
```

When my page loads for the first time, toggling works perfectly fine. However, when I change pages via my main navigation the toggling does not work anymore. I put an alert inside the click function and realized that AFTER page change the alert gets executed multiple times, namely as many times as I changed the page before.

The toggling works again when I move to the other page by entering the URL in my browser and loading the page.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If the alert executes many times on click after changing the page it may suggest that you have new click event listener bound on every page change. Try to unbind the click event listeners on that element before binding your click listener, to avoid such situation. Sth like that:

```
$('#toggle-sidebar').off('click');
$('#toggle-sidebar').on('click', function() {
   $('#sidebar').toggleClass('visible');
});
```

It may resolve the issue.

You may also take a look at jQuery event namespaces https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/. And add namespace to your click event so it won't unbind other click events on that element that may possibly appear in the code someday.